# Values of $a$ for which the series converges

Tags: calculus

$$\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{\sqrt{an + 2} - 3\sqrt{n+1}}{4n}$$

The only thing I suspect I could do is to split the series in two as follows:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{\sqrt{an + 2}}{4n} - \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{3\sqrt{n+1}}{4n}$$

From that, I can conclude that the second series diverges, but I don't know what to do next.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Hint:** Multiply top and bottom by $\sqrt{an+2}+3\sqrt{n+1}$  and things should become clear. There will be precisely one "good" $a$.

**Remark:**  Splitting is not good. We end up looking at the "difference" between two divergent series.

Comment: When I do that, I end up with $\frac{n(a-9) - 7}{4n(\sqrt{an + 2} + 3\sqrt{n+1}}$. Can I conclude that for the series to converge, I need to eliminate $n(a-9)$, which will mean that it will converge for $a = 9$, or do I need some extra steps before that conclusion? Maybe checking for other values somehow?

Comment: For $a=9$, we have convergence. For the absolute value of the $n$-th term is $\lt \frac{7}{12n^{3/2}}$. To deal with $a\ne 0$, maybe first note the series is undefined for large $n$ if $a$ is negative, so we only care about positive $a$. After a while sign does not change, so a Limit Comparison with $\sum n^{-1/2}$, which diverges, tells us the series diverges.

Comment: @Proka As an unrelated question, how is eliminating $n(a-9)$ making  the series converge? I'm not understanding your work.

Comment: @VishwaIyer: Well, if $n(a-9)$ is eliminated, I am left with $\frac{-7}{4n(\sqrt{an + 2}+3\sqrt{n+1})}$ and I can conclude that it converges based on the comparison test (I just translated it from my native language, not sure if it's actually called "comparison test" in English).

Comment: Informally, eliminating that term makes the thing behave like a constant times $\sum \frac{1}{n^{3/2}}$, which converges. If we still have a constant times $n$ in the numerator, the terms are "too big" for the sum to exist.

Comment: If $a=9$, the terms have absolute value $\le \frac{7}{12n^{3/2}}$.

Answer (score 1):

For $a=0$ you don't have convergence, for $a\neq0$ you can write
$$\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{\sqrt{an + 2} - 3\sqrt{n+1}}{4n}=$$$$=\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{4n}\left[\sqrt{an}\left(1+\frac{1}{an}+o\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)\right)-3\sqrt{n}\left(1+\frac{1}{n}+o\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)\right)\right]\ ,$$
in order to have convergence you need the leading term to be zero, i.e. $\sqrt{a}=3$, i.e. $a=9$.